# How do I set permission of file on samba network drive from windows

Tags: linux, windows, samba

I am accessing network drive (Z:\stream) on windows. Now the permission set on stream folder is like chmod -R 777 streams/ means all the files inside stream is at 777 but now i am copying some files from windows to this streams folder but  permission on those files are not 777 ,i would like to have permission 777 on those files that copied from windows ...how do i do that??

Answer (score 1):

On linux:

Once you copy, you can run chmod again

chmod -R 777 `<dir>`

Comment: but i can't go to linux machine again from windows i have to do that...

Answer (score 0):

If your Windows version allows it, use the standard Windows file permission interface under *Properties → Security* and grant "Read", "Write" and "Execute" (or simply "Full control") permissions to all items listed. (There should be three; the owner, the group, and "Everyone"). Samba will automatically translate them to Unix permissions or to POSIX ACLs.

[image: Windows security properties]

A command-line method, one that only works for setting 0777, is `cacls myfile /g Everyone:F`.